How to manage .env files in the turbo repo
I created turbo-repo which contains:

Next js app (2)
express app (1)
database package (1)

Now every app has its own .env file concerning its folder
Now I am to host this project on the VPS. The problem I am facing is how to manage all these .env files. in  a single project, I could either use the dotenv (ref: website) or even easily copy and paste to the server
but in the turbo repo, this is not the convenient way so how can handle the multiple .env files in the turbo repo.

The docs says that a best practice to deal this is using a local .env by package
https://turbo.build/repo/docs/crafting-your-repository/using-environment-variables#use-env-files-in-packages
